# Want to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto a secondary partition on a secondary drive

Tags: 14.04

I currently have two hard drives, a 240 SSD with Win7 on it and a 1 TB drive that I mainly use for storage.  I would like to partition off about 50 GB of the 1 TB drive and install Ubuntu 14.04 on it.  So right now, I went into Windows and there is about 50 GB of unallocated space for my Ubuntu install.  Can this be done?  I have tried installing Ubuntu on it, but it seems to take the entire 1 TB drive and use it all for Ubuntu.  I manually create all the partitions when installing, using 500MB for /boot, 15 GB for /, 4 GB for swap area and the rest of the remaining 50 GB for /home.  Once it installs though, the entire 1 TB drive is used for Ubuntu.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just choose **"something else"** when you get to the part of the installation where it asks if you want to install ubuntu "**along side**" or use the whole hard drive.

Then, you can right click on the existing partition. Will have the option to resize the partition. Resize the partition to 54 GB less than the original partition size.

Then, right click on **unallocated space** and select to create a new partition. Make this partition only 50 GB of the 54 available unallocated GB of space. Choose **"ext4"** type and set the mount point to "**/**".

Finally, right click on the remaining 4 GB of space and set the type to "**linux swap**" or "**swap space**".

Proceed with the installation.

Comment: I will try this later, thank you for the response.  In Win7, I did leave the 50GB as unallocated space and manually created the ubuntu partitions in the installer by choosing 'Something Else.'  But it still just took over the entire 1 TB drive, including the already existing ~900GB that was partitioned in Win7 as primary.